# how to populate autocompletetextview with string array created in a class

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Generally `AutoCompleteTextView` is populated with `strings.xml` file in `res/values` folder. Can anyone tell me how to use a string array created in the class to populate `AutoCompleteTextView`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this...

```
autocompletetextAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, stringArray);

myAutocompleteTextView.setAdapter(autocompletetextAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

simply by creating a public method like: getArray () in the class where the array is obtained then you use it with your autocomplete textview

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
((AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1)).setAdapter(
    new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
        String_array));
```

where `autoCompleteTextView1` is your Autocompletetextview field name  String_array is the array  you wanted to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

`result_auto_txt.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(RegisterEmployeeActivity.this,               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.result)));`

This is very help for `string.xml` to list using
array.